# Cannot convert value of type '(TVSessionConfigurationBuilder!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'TVSessionConfigurationBuilderBlock!'

Tags: ios, swift, teamviewer

Just followed the iOS TeamViewer SDK tutorial but it won't work for me using Swift.

```
let sessionConfiguration : TVSessionConfiguration = TVSessionConfiguration.tvSessionConfigurationWithBlock(
{
    (builder: TVSessionConfigurationBuilder!) -> Void in
    builder.sessionCode = "SESSION_CODE"
})
```

Gives the error in the title.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
let sessionConfiguration = TVSessionConfiguration(block: { builder in
    builder?.sessionCode = "SESSION_CODE"            
})
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps it's better to use optional unwrapping for `builder` (`?` instead of `!`)